# Explode a string column with dictionary structure in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like this-

| RowNumber | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{mail=abc@xyz.com, Name=abc}, {mail=mnc@xyz.com, Name=mnc}] |
| 2 | [{mail=klo@xyz.com, Name=klo}, {mail=mmm@xyz.com, Name=mmm}] |

The column "value" is of string type.

```
root
  |--value: string (nullable = false)
  |--rowNumber: integer (nullable = false)
```

**Step 1** I need to explode the  dictionaries inside the list on each row under column "value" like this-

[image]

**Step 2** And then to further explode the column so that the resultant table looks like :

[image]

Although When I try to get to **Step1** using:

```
df.select(explode(col('value')).alias('value'))
```

it shows me error:

> Analysis Exception: cannot resolve 'explode("value")' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string

How do I convert this string under column 'value' to compatible data types so that I can proceed with exploding the dictionary elements as valid array/json (step1) and then into separate columns (step2) ?

please help

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There may be a simpler way to do this with the `from_json` function and `StructTypes`, for that you can check out [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-from_json-convert-json-column-to-struct-map-or-multiple-columns/) link.

### The `ast` way

To parse a string as a dictionary or list in Python, you can use the `ast` library's `literal_eval` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#function-and-class-definitions). If we convert this function to a PySpark UDF, then the following code will suffice:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType
from ast import literal_eval

literal_eval_udf = udf(literal_eval, ArrayType(MapType()))

table = table.withColumn("value", literal_eval_udf(col("value"))) # Make strings into ArrayTypes of MapTypes
table = table.withColumn("value", explode(col("value"))) # Explode ArrayTypes such that each row contains a MapType
```

After applying these functions to the table, what should remain is what you originally referred to as the start of "step 2." From here, we want to split each `"value"` column key into a column with entries from the corresponding value. This is accomplished with another function application which gives us the dict values:

```py
table = table.withColumn("value", map_values(col("value")))
```

Now the `values` column contains an `ArrayType` of the values contained in each dictionary. To make a separate column for each of these, we simply add them in a loop:

```py
keys = ['mail', 'Name']
for k in range(len(keys)):
  table = table.withColumn(keys[k], table.value[k])
```

Then you can drop the original `value` column because we wouldn't need it anymore, as you'll now have the columns `mail` and `Name` with the information from the corresponding maps.

Comment: I am getting error while trying to call the literal_eval function:

``` TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'keyType' and 'valueType' ```